# Prove the given inequality $\mid\sqrt{2}-c_{n+1}\mid <\frac{\mid\sqrt{2}-c_{n}\mid}{1+\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Given,

> $$\sqrt{2}-c_{n+1}= \sqrt{2}+\frac{c_n+2}{c_n+1}$$

I converted the form in R.H.S ,

$$\sqrt{2}+\frac{c_n+2}{c_n+1}=\frac{(\sqrt{2}+c_{n})(1+\sqrt{2})}{1+c_{n}}$$

then did as following,

$$\mid\sqrt{2}-c_{n+1}\mid <\frac{\mid\sqrt{2}-c_{n}\mid}{1+\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \mid\frac{(\sqrt{2}+c_{n})(1+\sqrt{2})}{1+c_{n}}\mid <\frac{\mid\sqrt{2}-c_{n}\mid}{1+\sqrt{2}}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\mid\sqrt{2}+c_{n}\mid\mid1+\sqrt{2}\mid}{\mid\sqrt{2}-c_{n}\mid\mid1+c_{n}\mid}<\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}$$

I tried a lot, but got stuck here .How it can be proved after this? Or any other method to prove !!

Comment: I have given the relation at the starting of my explanation.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry about that. I will think about this.

Comment: @OP: are you sure you didn't mean $|\sqrt 2-c_{n+1}|=\sqrt 2\color{red}{-}\frac{c_n+2}{c_n+1}$ ?

Comment: Nope!! it's given the + sign in the problem.Even I found if it's -ve then it's quite easily solvable. But it's not!!

Comment: It looks to me like it is false.   If $c_n= \sqrt2$, then the inequality if false for any $c_{n+1}$, but there exist two real values of $c_{n+1}$ that satisfy the hypothesis.

Comment: A problem is that $c_{n+1}$ is not uniquely determined. It can be either greater or less than $\sqrt{2}$. So consider those two cases separately.

Comment: I have made a correction of the given relation.That's not the absolute value .Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, the inequality does not hold.  Below I have put some sample values for $c_n$, $c_{n+1}= - \frac{c_n+2}{c_n+1}$, the infimum and the supremum of the set of values for $c_{n+1}$ where the inequality holds, and whether the inequality holds.

\begin{array}{cccccc}
 c_n & c_{n+1} & \text{Numerical}\  c_{n+1} & \inf & \sup  & \text{Inequality} \\
 -4 & -\frac{2}{3} & -0.666667 & 2-2 \sqrt{2} & 4 \sqrt{2}-2 & \text{True} \\
 -3 & -\frac{1}{2} & -0.5 & 1-\sqrt{2} & 3 \sqrt{2}-1 & \text{False} \\
 -\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} & -0.333333 & \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2} & \text{False} \\
 -2 & 0 & 0. & 0 & 2 \sqrt{2} & \text{False} \\
 -\frac{9}{5} & \frac{1}{4} & 0.25 & \frac{1}{5} \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) & \frac{1}{5} \left(1+9 \sqrt{2}\right) & \text{True} \\
 -\frac{3}{2} & 1 & 1. & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}} & \text{True} \\
 -\frac{1}{2} & -3 & -3. & \frac{3}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) & \frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \text{False} \\
 0 & -2 & -2. & 2 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) & 2 & \text{False} \\
 1 & -\frac{3}{2} & -1.5 & 3 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) & 3-\sqrt{2} & \text{False} \\
 \sqrt{2} & -\sqrt{2} & -1.41421 & \sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & \text{False} \\
 2 & -\frac{4}{3} & -1.33333 & 4-2 \sqrt{2} & 4 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) & \text{False} \\
 3 & -\frac{5}{4} & -1.25 & 5-3 \sqrt{2} & 5 \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) & \text{False} \\
\end{array}

Comment: Ok I got it.But suppose you're given this and you have to prove" inequality doesn't hold" ,then how you can prove it quite in a logical way(not like above ,although I got the idea above!) @irchans

Comment: @Invnto   I don't have time right now, but I think that you can prove that the inequality does not hold when $\sqrt2<c_n<2+2\sqrt2$ using algebra and the fact that $c_{n+1}<0$ when $c_n$ is in that interval.  I suggest you spend some time trying that, and, if you can't do it that way, I will add that algebra to my answer above.

Comment: @Invnto   Also, I think you will understand what is happening if you graph both the hypothesis equation and the inequality setting $(x,y)$ to $(c_n, c_{n+1})$.

Comment: yeah!! thanks for the hint irchans.I can do it now.